# How to kill processes owned by rdsadmin user in aurora aws mysql DB?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, kill-process, lock-timeout

I have to kill processes owned by rdsadmin user in aurora aws mysql DB, for which I don't have access to.

I have tried to kill process by following ways, but it didn't work.

1. mysql> CALL mysql.rds_kill(9);
   ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ERROR (RDS): CANNOT KILL RDSADMIN SESSION' in 'field list'
2. mysql> kill 9;
   ERROR 1095 (HY000): You are not owner of thread 9

Comment: don't kill RDS Admin threads, nothing good can come of that.  What's the underlying  problem your'e trying to solve?

Comment: Luckily you do not have permission to do that. Doing so would break your RDS Aurora deployment in unknown ways. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am deploying changes through yoyo migration and when it hits with backend.lock() from yoyo migration, it waits for around 30 seconds and returns exception that “lockTimeout: Process 9 has locked this database (run yoyo break-lock to remove this lock)”. Where process 9 is owned by rdsadmin which is in sleep.